# Integrating perf4J with maven and logback

Tags: maven, aspectj, slf4j, logback, perf4j

I am having problems integrating perf4j in an existing maven application. 
I tried several approaches, but none of them seemed to work, so I was wondering if anyone has some insight into how this is done.
What I want to do is use the AOP part of perf4j on some methods and log them into a different file than the one used for app logging. 
 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might be suffering from the same declaration order issue as mentioned in another [perf4j/logback related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850352/perf4j-settings-for-logback-xml). In short, it is always a good idea to [enable printing of logback's internal status messages](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#automaticStatusPrinting) by setting the `debug` attribute to true within the `configuration` element. Also do not forget that [any referenced appender must be declared beforehand](http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#appender_order).